# Group By mostrar quando não tem na tabela

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tenho a tabela abaixo em MySQL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria buscar os usuários que tem a cor AZUL mas não tem a cor VERDE, ou seja, nessa tabela iria me listar o usuário 3 apenas, tentei assim:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario_cor WHERE tipo = 'azul' AND tipo != 'verde' GROUP BY id_usuario
```

Sei que não está certo, qual a forma de se fazer isso?

Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, amigo!
Você pode fazer isso de duas formas. Exemplo:

```
    SELECT * 
        FROM usuario_cor t1 WHERE t1.Tipo = 'azul' 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                            FROM usuario_cor t
                        WHERE t.ID_usuario = t1.id_Usuario 
                            AND t.tipo ='verde')
    /*    OU     */

    SELECT t1.* 
        FROM usuario_cor t1
        LEFT JOIN usuario_cor t2 ON t2.id_usuario = t1.id_usuario and t2.tipo = 'verde'
        WHERE t1.Tipo = 'azul' 
        AND t2.id_usuario IS NULL
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraço,